# Why is my function not returning the JSON Array items I want?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a function where I'm trying to put some contents of a json file into an element. I receive this array from a function in the backend. My function prints out the same amount of objects, but not the specific items I'm trying to grab. The console log prints out the array just fine, so I know that part is working.

JSON Array Example

```
 [
    { "Type":"Ford", "Model":"mustang" },
    { "Type":"Dodge", "Model":"ram" }
  ]
```

HTML

```
<p id="special"></p>
```

JS

```
myMethod: function () {
            var res = this;
            fetch('/cont/function', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(function (data) {
                    res.type = data.Type;
                    console.log(data);
                    var html = '';
                    data.forEach(function (these) {
                        html += { these: res.type };
                    });
                    document.getElementById('special').innerHTML = html;
                });
        }
```

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: ``html += {} ` you're assignin an object to a variable you'll consider as a string

Comment: `data` is an array, so `data.Type` is undefined. In the `forEach` loop, `these` is an Object (each object in your array), so `html += { these: res.type }` makes no sense. To an HTML string, you are adding an object whose key is an object and value is undefined.

Comment: what do u return mean? there is no return method in function . Function just append to html . Does it append or not ?

Comment: @pc_coder It's not appending to the html. It just prints [object, Object] in the same length of the array.

Comment: problem is that you should stringfy json object and take data.Type inside loop .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues

- res not existing,
- type not existing (it is Type and JS is case sensitive)
- hmtl += an object does not work

A [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would have been useful like this:

```js
const data = [
    { "Type":"Ford", "Model":"mustang" },
    { "Type":"Dodge", "Model":"ram" }
  ]
  
var text = [];
data.forEach(function(these) {
  text.push(these.Type)
});
document.getElementById('special').textContent = text.join(", ");
```

```html
<div id="special"></div>
```

More details:

```js
const data = [
    { "Type":"Ford", "Model":"mustang" },
    { "Type":"Dodge", "Model":"ram" }
  ]
  
var html = [];
data.forEach(function(these) {
  html.push(`<li>${these.Type}: ${these.Model}</li>`)
});
document.getElementById('special').innerHTML = html.join("");
```

```html
<ul id="special"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're appending a JavaScript object to the html string, which would theoretically evaluate to `"[object Object]"` or something similar. If you want the `{}`s to display in the HTML itself, then simply wrap the object in quotations, or call `JSON.stringify(obj)`, to it. Secondly, you are trying to set the key of the object to the reference for the object itself, but the keys themselves, unless surrounded by `[]`s, don't reflect the local variable; rather, the literal string itself.

So here "these" is a variable name attempted to be referenced in the JSON key, but as a key, it would evaluate to just the string literal "these", to fix these problems, surround "these" in brackets and JSON.stringify the whole thing, or the entire object in `"`s and concat the variable value to it, so either:

```
var html = '';
data.forEach(function (these) {
  html += "{ " + these + ": " + res.type + "}"/*or some other string based on */;
});
```

or

```
var html = '';
data.forEach(function (these) {
  html += JSON.stringify({ [these]: res.type })/*or some other string based on */;
});
```

Comment: ... but `these === { "Type":"Ford", "Model":"mustang" }`, so, `{ [these]: res.type }` makes no sense. Besides, `res` is undefined. Stringify it all and you still get nonsense.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input!